# Scrapy shell keeps returning invalid syntax in terminal

Tags: python, shell, terminal, scrapy

I am trying to launch scrapy shell in terminal. However it keeps giving invalid syntax error. I am using Python 2.7.13 and Mac Sierra 10.12.6.

```
>>> import scrapy
>>> scrapy shell 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
File "<stdin>", line 1
scrapy shell 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thanks lot!

Comment: That's a shell command, not a Python command. Get out of Python first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not use this in the Python interpreter.  It was meant to be run in a terminal

You must not execute this in the Python interpreter but open a [Terminal](https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac-software/how-use-terminal-on-mac-3608274/) and run it in that instead.